# Trying to find pathlib equivalent to str.find() in filepath in python

Tags: python

I am trying to remove string manipulation of paths using pathlib module.
my initial code was:

```
file = "root/folder1/test/sample.py"

if file.find("/test/") != -1 and file.endswith(".py"):
    doSomething()
```

For str.endswith() i found path.suffix, but i could not find something to replace str.find().

Here file is a pathlib.Path and not a string.
I tried following but not getting the expected results:

```
if file.match("/test/") and file.suffix in [".py"]:
    doSomething()
```

I also tried `rglob()` but no luck.

Am i missing something here...?
Thanks in advance...!

Comment: Why do you need the same methods on Path and string?  Just call `str(file)` and do whatever you want with that path string